# Need first ul has 1 li and each ul has 5 li

Tags: php

I need this type of structure in PHP foreach loop. and i tried this code :

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

i tried this condition inside loop and working fine but i need 1 li on first ul.

```
<?php
$counter = 1;
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :

  setup_postdata($post); 

  if ($counter % 5 == 1) {
    echo '<ul>';
  }
  echo '<li>testing ...</li>'

  if($counter % 5 == 0) {
    echo '</ul>';
  }
  $counter++;
endforeach;
?>
```

any one extend my logic ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
$myposts = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16);

$counter = 0;
echo '<ul>';
foreach( $myposts as $k=>$post ) :
    //setup_postdata($post); 
    echo '<li>'.$post.'</li>';
    if($counter==0 || $counter==5){
        echo "</ul>".($k!=count($myposts)-1 ? "<ul>" : "");
        $counter = 0;
    }
    $counter++;
endforeach;
if($counter==5){
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

This largest misconception most people don't bother to close that last tag (in your case `ul`), or they open a new tag (in your case `ul`) when they shouldn't.

P.s. I had to comment `setup_postdata` for this to work.

**Note:** Adding or removing elements from the array will not effect the structure of 1,5,5,...,(then remainder depending on what is left)

Comment: why you comment `setup_postdata` ?

Comment: you should un-comment it. i had to, in order to make the script work for me, otherwise I get an `undefined function` error

Comment: as you said "misconception most people don't bother to close that last tag" is it valid ?? if yes then why ?

Comment: certainly, most people will forget to close the ending tag. It has a minimal effect when using `</ul>` but if you were trying to do the same thing with `<div>` then it could mess up your entire page.

Comment: Thank you friend for answer.